# android: Why onDestroy not be called when i call finish?

Tags: android

In  my code i call finish on a activity but the onDestroy method of this activity not be called. would anyone can tell me why? when the onDestroy method will be called?

Comment: Here is what documentation says about onDestory `The final call you receive before your activity is destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.`, so post your code

Comment: i see the sorce code found the problem is  the activity's parent not null,if it's that finish() method will not work itself but his parent

Answer (score 0):

onDestroy() is called only when system is low on resources(memory, cpu time and so on) and makes a decision to kill your activity/application or when somebody calls finish() on your activity.

So, to test your code() you can make a test button, that will call finish() on your activity.

I believe you don't need to call all this stuff in onDestroy() until adap is not a critical resource. And even in that case android system has mechanisms to properly dispose them.

For More Details you can Refer [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29)

Comment: please refrain from using abbreviations like U, in stackoverflow posts. You are not writing sms to your buddies.

Comment: the problem is the activity's parent not null,if it that finish() method will not work itself but his parent